# Facing Error in npm install live-server -g? How to resolve i?t

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFXZU.png)

Facing An error while i use npm install live-server -g please give me some idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing it globally install it locally.

First clear the `npm` chache.

```
&> npm cache clean --force
```

Then install it as local package.

```
$> npm i live-server
```